# How to configure ufw to limit only failed ssh connections, not successful ones?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, ufw

My OS is Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Is it possible to configure `ufw limit` -rule for remote ssh so that it limits only failed ssh connection attempts? Now it limits also successful ssh connections, which is annoying if e.g. a script calls another scripts which all run short remote ssh tasks. This will cause the script to fail at some point.

```
jk@vm04:~/Documents$ date ; ssh jk@srvr02 -p 12345 date
Sat 29.10.2022 13.59.50 +0300
Sat 29 Oct 2022 01:59:51 PM EEST
jk@vm04:~/Documents$ date ; ssh jk@srvr02 -p 12345 date
Sat 29.10.2022 13.59.53 +0300
Sat 29 Oct 2022 01:59:53 PM EEST
jk@vm04:~/Documents$ date ; ssh jk@srvr02 -p 12345 date
Sat 29.10.2022 13.59.54 +0300
Sat 29 Oct 2022 01:59:55 PM EEST
jk@vm04:~/Documents$ date ; ssh jk@srvr02 -p 12345 date
Sat 29.10.2022 13.59.55 +0300
Sat 29 Oct 2022 01:59:56 PM EEST
jk@vm04:~/Documents$ date ; ssh jk@srvr02 -p 12345 date
Sat 29.10.2022 13.59.56 +0300
Sat 29 Oct 2022 01:59:57 PM EEST
jk@vm04:~/Documents$ date ; ssh jk@srvr02 -p 12345 date
Sat 29.10.2022 13.59.58 +0300
ssh: connect to host srvr02 port 12345: Connection refused
jk@vm04:~/Documents$ date ; ssh jk@srvr02 -p 12345 date
Sat 29.10.2022 14.00.28 +0300
Sat 29 Oct 2022 02:00:29 PM EEST
jk@vm04:~/Documents$ date ; ssh jk@srvr02 -p 12345 date
Sat 29.10.2022 14.00.30 +0300
Sat 29 Oct 2022 02:00:31 PM EEST
jk@vm04:~/Documents$ date ; ssh jk@srvr02 -p 12345 date
Sat 29.10.2022 14.00.31 +0300
Sat 29 Oct 2022 02:00:32 PM EEST
jk@vm04:~/Documents$ date ; ssh jk@srvr02 -p 12345 date
Sat 29.10.2022 14.00.33 +0300
Sat 29 Oct 2022 02:00:33 PM EEST
jk@vm04:~/Documents$ date ; ssh jk@srvr02 -p 12345 date
Sat 29.10.2022 14.00.34 +0300
Sat 29 Oct 2022 02:00:34 PM EEST
jk@vm04:~/Documents$ date ; ssh jk@srvr02 -p 12345 date
Sat 29.10.2022 14.00.35 +0300
ssh: connect to host srvr02 port 12345: Connection refused
```

`man ufw` says about limits:

```
ufw  supports connection rate limiting, which is useful for protecting against brute-force
       login attacks. When a limit rule is used, ufw will normally allow the connection but  will
       deny  connections  if  an  IP address attempts to initiate 6 or more connections within 30
       seconds. See http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/187 for details. Typical  usage
       is:

       ufw limit ssh/tcp
```

The given link on the man page is broken.

Related ufw rule is:

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                   Action      From
--                   ------      ----
12345                LIMIT IN    Anywhere       (log) # ssh
```

When I change the rule to:

```
12345                ALLOW       Anywhere       (log) # ssh
```

scripts run without `ssh: ... Connection refused` -errors.

So is it possible to limit only failed connection attempts instead of all connection attempts with ufw settings and configuration?

If ufw does not help here, what is the best option? Maybe fail2ban?

Comment: Nope. A firewall only controls the network traffic to an SSH port; port 22. It has no knowledge as to whether that connection succeeded or not. Tools like Fail2Ban are what you want to use. Fail2Ban works with SSH logs to keep track of failed logins. But unsure if it works with UFW. It definitely works with IPtables; I have been using it successfully with an Ubuntu 20.04 server for years.

Comment: `fail2ban` is capable of doing exactly that, and even more. It checks log output of different services and creates temporary firewall rules (also compatible with `ufw`) if it finds a match. You can set it to lock a port for a certain timeframe, or to only block an IP.

Comment: you might consider fail2ban, pam_tally2 or pam-abl as alternatives.